# Save/Load player position and relative scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem. I did the script for saving the player but it only saves the position and not the scene. So if the player saves in scene A and reloads the game when he is in the same scene A there is no problem. However, when the player saves in a scene A and then loads the game into another scene B, the saved scene (ie the A) is not loaded, but only the position of scene A, applied to the current scene B. How would it be save the position and the related scene, including the progress in the scene itself?

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour { 
    public int level; 
    public int collected; 
    public float health; 
    public Image healthBar;
    public float currentHealth; 
    public bool win;

    private void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = health;
        Clue2.objectsCollected = collected;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        collected = Clue2.objectsCollected;
        level = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;       
    }
    public void SavePlayer()
    {
        SaveSystem.SavePlayer(this);
        Debug.Log("Saved: " + this);
    }

    public void LoadPlayer()
    {
       PlayerData data = SaveSystem.LoadPlayer();   
       level = data.level;      
       health = data.health;
       collected = data.collected;
       Clue2.objectsCollected = collected;
       win = data.win;

       Vector3 position;
       position.x = data.position[0];
       position.y = data.position[1];
       position.z = data.position[2];
       transform.position = position;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;
        healthBar.fillAmount = currentHealth / health;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public int level;
    public int collected;
    public float health;        
    public float[] position;
    public bool win;

    public PlayerData(Player player)
    {
        level = player.level;
        health = player.level;      
        collected = player.collected;
        win = player.win;

        //x,y,z
        position = new float[3];
        position[0] = player.transform.position.x;
        position[1] = player.transform.position.y;
        position[2] = player.transform.position.z;
    }
}


public static class SaveSystem
{
    public static void SavePlayer(Player player)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerData.dat";

        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        PlayerData data = new PlayerData(player);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
        Debug.Log(path);
    }

    public static PlayerData LoadPlayer()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerData.dat";

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            PlayerData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
            stream.Close();

            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("not found " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sooo...you don't include the scene information in your `PlayerData` class. You expected the scene to persist...how, exactly?

Comment: I tried to include the scene, but when the save is loaded the scene is loaded from the beginning.

Comment: Then you need to transition scenes.

Comment: transitions? are they like animations? sorry, but I'm starting out with unity and I've never heard of transitions.

Comment: *`Transition, the process or a period of changing from one state or condition to another.`* This is not some fancy C# or Unity word, its English. You're already changing scenes some how. You need to do that again when you load the player's data.

Comment: I will consult the docs, thanks for the help